# Making a navigation 3D cube

Tags: c#, 3d, cube

I'm trying to make a 3D cube in Microsoft Visual Studio, and what I'm trying to get it to do is let you drag it around with your mouse.
(Ex. Grab the cube with left click and holding and then dragging around your screen to rotate it 3D)

is this possible to do with c#?

Comment: Please don't put tags in title and try to add tags that are related to your question (or explain how they are related - i.e. "browser" tag as "something related to web browser" is hard to clearly relate to your post).

Answer (score 0):

This is easy to implement in `WPF` [Introduction to WPF 3D](http://wpftutorial.net/Behaviors.html) and using [Behaviors](http://wpftutorial.net/Behaviors.html) for making it drag-able

Answer (score 0):

You can use transformation in WPF, or use opengl in C#, see this [post](http://xinyustudio.wordpress.com/2008/12/01/using-opengl-in-c-taoframework/).